# custom error window/handling in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I'm currently building an application for file backup, and it got quite a bit of reading and writing to the filesystem. Most of it works great, but I'm struggling a bit with the error handling of the app.

In the screenshot below the last path is not a valid directory and return an exception as you can see.

[image]

```
function getTotalSize(pathToDir, dir) {
fs.readdir(pathToDir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        // handle my error here
        throw new Error('something bad happened');
        return;
    }

    // continue if no errors :)
```

My question is, is it possible to replace the standard error window with my own? Or in some cases ignore the pop up of the error window? First time working with Electron so sorry if this is an obvious one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you throw the error from `readdir` it gets caught by the top-level `uncaughtException` handler, indicated by the the first line: "Uncaught Exception".

What you need to do is add your own custom handler for the [`uncaughtException`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) in your main process and show whatever dialog you want from there.

Take a look at the [`dialog`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options-callback) module.

As an example, you can use the `dialog.showMessageBox` method to configure all sorts of things about the error dialog like this:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
   const messageBoxOptions = {
        type: "error",
        title: "Error in Main process",
        message: "Something failed"
    };
    dialog.showMessageBoxSync(messageBoxOptions);

    // I believe it used to be the case that doing a "throw err;" here would
    // terminate the process, but now it appears that you have to use's Electron's
    // app module to exit (process.exit(1) seems to not terminate the process)
    app.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for some parts of the code like `require` statements.

Comment: @m4heshd is it just a matter of hooking the `uncaughtException` event before all your top-level imports? (though it does look weird)

Comment: Still it does happen for some reason. I've pretty much tried everything since Electron v3 or something. Just gave up.