# Catch an errors in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

Good afternoon!

How to intercept an error(s) in the main process of the ElectronJS application with sqllite3?
It seems that the **try-catch** construction does not work in the "standard way" in Electron apps.

preload.js

```
deleteMainMenuItem: (id) => ipcRenderer.invoke("delete-main-menu-item", id)
```

main.js

```
ipcMain.handle("delete-main-menu-item", (event, id) => {
  try {
    db.run("DELETE FROM projects_ErrOrNaMe WHERE id=?", [id]); //here error occured
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error); //this code is never works
  }
});
```

At the same time, a standard error window show out on top of an application like this. How to intercept?
[image]

Does electron have a different principle of working with errors, or am I being stupid somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686010/custom-error-window-handling-in-electron/50703424#50703424

Comment: I don't know what `db.run` is, but I'm guessing it's throwing the exception in a particular way that evades the standard try/catch. It's not really an Electron issue as far as I can tell

Comment: Yes, you're right. The try-catch construction works fine in the main Electron process in other cases. And the error that occurs when querying the database via db.run (sqlite3) is an unhandled error (uncaughtException). It needs to be intercepted in the process, as you indicated with the link above. Thanks!